Allure report using the Robot Framework in a Java-based environment
I am trying to generate Allure reports using the Robot Framework in a Java-based environment. My requirements are:

Not to use any listeners.

Not to use Python (this is a strict project requirement).


What I Have Tried

I used the robotframework-maven-plugin to execute Robot Framework tests.

The reports are being generated using an XML file (output.xml), but they only show limited data.

The detailed log steps visible in log.html are missing in the Allure reports.



Here is the Maven plugin configuration I am using:
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>run-robot-tests</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- Path for your Robot test cases -->
              <testCasesDirectory>src\main\java\com\example</testCasesDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>target/allure-results</outputDirectory>
              
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

Problem
The Allure report is generated, but:

It only includes limited data from the output.xml.

Detailed log steps available in log.html are not present in the report.


What I Expected
The Allure report should include detailed test execution logs (steps), similar to those visible in log.html.
What I Need Help With

How can I ensure that the Allure report includes detailed log steps from the test execution?

Are there any additional configurations or transformations needed for the output.xml file to include all necessary data for Allure?



Feel free to suggest improvements or a better approach that still adheres to the following restrictions:

No listeners.

No Python libraries or scripts.


